# Cant run Terminal from Finder with shortcut if 'Show items as' is on 'columns'

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, services, finder

I usually use 'show as columns' when working on my macbook. Today I assigned a shortcut to open terminal window from Finder in `sys -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services`, but it seems to work on every 'show as' option but columns view.

Can anyone explain why isn't it working and is there a way to make it work with columns view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that's because it is impossible to select a folder and not go inside of it in the 'columns' view, and terminal can only be opened when any folder is preselected.